# How can I center the contents of a div, around a specific element?

Tags: html, css

I'm using html and css.
a link to the problem https://codepen.io/rybohi/pen/vYLpNzK

I have

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="yellow"></div>
</div>
```

currently I can center the items, using css `justify-content:center;`
However what I want is to have the "green" div smack bang in the center and then to have the blue div and yellow div surrounding it, and the red div next to the blue div.

I've tried justify-self-center but to no prevail, when i place the green div relative and left 50vw, none of the other divs gets centered and the green div is also not smack bang center.

example:

You can see that the part where the blue and green meet is the very center of the page.
How can i make it that the middle of the green is where the center of the page is?
[image]

Comment: This part "the blue div and yellow div surrounding it, and the red div next to the blue div" is not clear !

Comment: @Ryan you want to stack the div one over the other?

Comment: I will edit and show examples

Comment: I have made an edit

Answer (score 0):

1. Add another wrapper: `<div>`

```
.containerparent {
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

and for the container you have set `width` property to be a bit bigger, and then change `justify-contant: start`. that way the green div will be in the middle of your pages as you wish.

https://codepen.io/yael-screenovate/pen/eYJEqRB?editors=1100

Comment: it needs to be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You could set `margin-left: -100px` of the element with the class of `.red` and make your `span` elements flex containers.

See below for a demo:

```css
div{
  width:100px; height:100px;
}

span {
  display: flex;
}

.container{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}

.red{
  background-color:red;
  margin-left: -100px;
}
.blue{
  background-color:blue;
  
}
.green{
  background-color:green;
}
.yellow{
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>
     <div class="red"></div>
      <div class="blue"></div>
  </span>
  <span>
    <div class="green"></div>
  </span>
  <span>
    <div class="yellow"></div>
    </span>
</div>
```